# Apache Rewrite Rule With % characters

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I have a url that needs to be rewritten.

http://aplus-carpetcleaning.com/home.php%3Fcity%3DGainesville%2520VA

I have tried this:

```
^home\.php%3Fcity%3DGainesville%2520VA$ "http://aplus-carpetcleaning.com/home.php?city=Gainevilles%20VA"
```

This is not being recognized. Tried various alternates but no dice.

**Notes:**

- `%3F` is '?'
- `%3D` is '=',
- `%2520` is who knows?

Comment: `%2520` is a space that has been encoded twice : a. ' ' character to `%20` url-encoded string, b. '%' character to `%25` url-encoded string gives `%2520` overall.

Comment: `%25` is the escaped percent sign (`%`). So `%2520` is a doubly-escaped space (an escaped "%20"). Just consult an ASCII code chart.

Answer (score 1):

The rewriting module applies your regex patterns to decoded urls, not the urlencoded string you see inside the browsers url field.

So create your regex pattern using unescaped characters instead. Something like:

```
^home.php\?city=Gainesville&20VA$
```

Comment: Ahem, how exactly? We want to know!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with:

```
RewriteRule ^home\.php(.*)city(.*)Gainesville(.*)VA$ "http:\/\/aplus\-carpetcleaning\.com\/home\.php?city=Gainesville VA" [R=301,L]
```